# Why won't these child divs align to the right-side of their parent?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a simple UI with the following design:

[image]

But am getting the following (I added solid red lines around each `<div>`s border so I could see div borders; will be removing them once everything is placed correctly):

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Options</title>
    <style>
        #control-panel-div {
            right: 0px;
        }
    </style>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="option-sel-div" style="border: 1px solid red;">
            <select id="provider-sel">
                <option selected="selected" id="default">Select an option</option>
                <option id="1">option1</option>
                <option id="2">option2</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div id="config-manage-div" style="border: 1px solid red;">
            <div id="control-panel-div" style="border: 1px solid red;">
                <input id="add-config-btn" type="button" value="Add"/>

                <input id="remove-config-btn" type="button" value="Remove"/>
            </div>

            <div id="table-div" style="border: 1px solid red;">
                <div id="config-datatable">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Blah
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                bleh
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Fizz
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Buzz
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I *believe* that by setting `control-panel-div`'s `right` property have a value of 0px, then all of its children should be right-aligned, but for the life of me I can't get this to work (I have also tried `text-align`, and `box-align`). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I won't comment about using tables for this, but you can just change your CSS to:

```
#control-panel-div {
    text-align: right;
}​
```

to get the effect.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UBHBa/)**

Comment: Exactly what I was just about to post :)

Comment: Thanks @j08691 (+1) - just out of curiosity, why does `text-align` work, but not `right`? Shouldn't `text-align` only cover text-based elements?!?

Comment: The `text-align` property applies to inline content, so when you apply it to your `#control-panel-div` div, it affects the content, which in this case are inline input elements. For more info check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-align. And, right only applies to positioned elements. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/right for more info on that.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#control-panel-div {
    float: right;
}
```

Here is the doc if you need to read on the property: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: This works, too but i don't think it's entirely what pnongrata is looking for. +1 for an alternative :)

Comment: Yeah, I reread the question after and found out some bits I hadn't read correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Without much hassle, and with clearer markup:

```
<style type="text/css">
    form {
        width: 300px;
    }
    fieldset {
        float: right;
        border: 0;
    }
    table {
        clear: both;
    }
</style>

<form action="index.php">
    <select name="the_select">
        <option selected="selected" id="default">Select an option</option>
        <option id="1">option1</option>
        <option id="2">option2</option>
    </select>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Controls</legend>
        <button>Add</button>
        <button>Remove</button>
    </fieldset>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Blah
            </td>
            <td>
                bleh
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Fizz
            </td>
            <td>
                Buzz
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```